# causasive に and を

Tags: causation

I read a Japanese story and there is a sentence makes me confused.

> 去年の秋弟が重い病気になって、働けなくなってしまった。
>
> 弟はいつも「**兄さん一人に働かせて**すみません」と言っていました。

In my understanding, the 使役 grammar goes like

> S　は　[人]　を　[自動詞の使役の形]

So, the bolded sentence, in this logic, should be the form of

> **兄さんを働かせてすみません**
>
> 人 / 想像 / 知恵 を働かせる (online sentences)

Back to the original sentence, which one do native speakers prefer to use, に or を?

Comment: Not an answer but... 明鏡国語辞典 gives this example sentence: "せる〘助動詞〙①使役を表す。・・・「代理として娘**に/を**行かせる」"

Comment: [This](https://www.tomojuku.com/blog/shieki/shieki-jyoshi/) should answer the question. As for the examples, 兄さんに/兄さんを both works and do not change the meaning.